# Angular 8: How can i pass the updated parent data to Mat Dialog after updating both dialog data and parent data without closing dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-event-emitter, material-dialog

How can i pass the updated parent data to Mat Dialog after updating both dialog data and parent data without closing dialog?
Is any there any with `event emitter`?

I dont want to close the dialog. As to pass data i could have used `mat closed` function but i dont want to close the dialog, i just want to update both data without closing dialog.. basically to refresh the dialog data after update in parent data.